# Auto login with Kubuntu 14.10 KDE 5 plasma

Tags: kubuntu, auto-login

II've been trying to auto login, Kubuntu 14.10 KDE 5 plasma. I had this working by adding sddm.conf file in the etc dir containing:

```
[Autologin]
User=$USERNAME
Session=plasma.desktop
```

Substitute your user name for `$USERNAME`. Well, this "was"working fine.  I've been doing regular:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

While keeping an eye on sddm.conf file... It's still there, content unchanged, however, no more auto login!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to KDE settings
2. Go the "Login Screen" menu.
3. Go the Convenience tab.
4. Enable the "Auto-Login" checkbox.
5. Select your username from the dropdown.
6. ???
7. Profit.

Comment: This does not work in kubuntu, you can set it...but, it won't save

Comment: Did you enter administrative mode?

Comment: I had this working by adding sddm.conf file in the etc dir containing:
 
[Autologin]
User=$USERNAME
Session=plasma.desktop

Substitute your user name for $USERNAME 
 
Well, this "was"working fine.  I've been doing regular

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

While keeping an eye on sddm.conf file....its still there contents unchanged, however, no more auto login!

any suggestions?

Comment: Try `kdesu systemsettings` and follow the above steps.

Comment: system settings is where I did this...its a known issue, it won't save auto login

Comment: Or as an alternative for my end goal, is there a way in kubuntu, like in windows, to add an .exe file to a startup config, or folder, so the app will start up and run, for all users, before the login screen?

Comment: Yes. Definitely. That's a different question, though. Link it and I'll answer it.

Comment: I'm new to all this...how do I "link it" ?

Comment: Just paste the URL in a comment.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/538462/auto-login-with-kubuntu-14-10-kde-5-plasma/538472?noredirect=1#comment736595_538472

Comment: Your other question about running programs pre-login.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you at all.

Comment: Write a new question asking how to run programs pre-login. Post the link to that question here. Thanks!

Comment: ok, I asked the question "How can I start app before log on?"

Comment: The answerer refers to the KDE *4* system settings. The KCM he describes is used to configure the KDM display manager (of Plasma 4), not SDDM (used by Plasma 5).

Comment: Any screenshot?