# How can I start app before log on?

Tags: login

[Auto login with Kubuntu 14.10 KDE 5 plasma](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538462/auto-login-with-kubuntu-14-10-kde-5-plasma/538472?noredirect=1#comment736595_538472)

How can I start a VNC server before log on?

Comment: I see a post similar to this setting up a sh file vncserver.sh

Comment: I did this as shown, but when I run sudo update-rc.d vncserver defaults I get error ub2@ajub2-pc:/etc$ sudo update-rc.d vncserver defaults
insserv: Script vncserver is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script vncserver is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.

Answer (score 0):

Drop into Root:

```
sudo -s
```

First off, install `X11vnc`:

```
apt-get install x11vnc
```

Make a place for its files:

```
mkdir /etc/x11vnc
```

Set up auth:

```
x11vnc -storepasswd in /etc/x11vnc/passwd
x11vnc -storepasswd /etc/x11vnc/passwd
```

You will be asked to choose a password. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Edit the configs:

```
nano /etc/init/x11vnc.conf
```

Add this to the config:

```
start on login-session-start

script

sudo x11vnc -xkb -forever -auth /var/run/kdm/root/:0 -display :0 -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log

end script
```

Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Reboot and you can now use VNC.

[(Src)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen)

Comment: Do I need to do this ? "First off, install X11vnc:"  I already have realvnc installed

Comment: This did not work...I assume that x11vnc, is not "realVNC" but another vnc? I have to use "realVNC"...to long to explain why. Is there a way to star realVNC before login ?

Comment: Why realVNC? They all use the same protocol. X11VNC is a special VNC version designed for the X server. AFAIK, RealVNC will not work.